# Apache WS44J not taking environment variables correctly

Tags: java, properties, environment-variables, wss4j

I have a properties file in my spring boot application that uses environment variables

```
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.provider=org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.type=jks
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password=${env:keyStorePassword}
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias=${env:keyAlias}
org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file=${env:keyStoreFilePath}
```

However, it says it cannot find the file, while at the same time providing the path for the file. So it is pulling the value from the environment file correctly. I also copied and put the literal values instead of environment variables into the properties file, and it worked perfectly. Why is it that when I pull from the environment that it says it can't find the file?

This is the error log

```
17:06:12.537 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [<file>] using org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@38af3868 class loader.
17:06:12.542 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [<file>] using org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@38af3868 class loader.
17:06:12.559 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.util.Loader - Trying to find [<file>] using ClassLoader.getSystemResource().
17:06:12.568 [http-nio-8080-exec-1] DEBUG org.apache.ws.security.components.crypto.Merlin - <file> (No such file or directory)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: ${env:keyStoreFilePath} (No such file or directory)
```

The  tag is the exact same file path as in the environment variable.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you can create a test-case to reproduce the issue, then create a JIRA in the WSS4J project and attach the test-case there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this error, for reasons I still do not fully understand, the environment variable was being stored in some different format. So instead, I injected the variables into the properties file by using some good old java.

```
try {
    PropertiesConfiguration props = new PropertiesConfiguration(System.getenv("SIGNATURE_PROPS_FILE"));
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.password", System.getenv("KEY_STORE_PASSWORD"));
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.alias", System.getenv("KEY_ALIAS"));
    props.setProperty("org.apache.ws.security.crypto.merlin.keystore.file", System.getenv("KEY_STORE_FILE"));
    props.save();
    logger.debug("** signature.properties updated Successfully!! **");
} catch (ConfigurationException e) {
    logger.error(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: Facing same issue with springboot fat jar.  failing for me when it is trying to save(). because it is trying to modify the inside the jar